DocumentIntelligence extract tax base value
I'm using documentIntelligence to extract elements from receipt. The tax details are shown in the following structure:

My question is: How could I modify this result to make the recognition return me also the tax base value. In this case 1.36.

Combine the extracted tax base value with the tax details and format the information as a structured output, possibly in a dictionary or JSON format, with keys for the tax base value and the tax details.


How could I modify this result to make the recognition return me also the tax base value. In this case 1.36.

Before extracting tax details, you need to locate the tax base value in the receipt. This might involve searching for keywords like "Tax Base," "Subtotal," or any other indication of the base amount before taxes.

Once you've identified the location of the tax base value, you can extract it using document Intelligence from the receipt.

import re

# Sample receipt text
receipt_text = "Subtotal: $1.36\nTax Details: IVA (21%): $0.29, IGIC (7%): $0.07"

# Define regular expression pattern to capture subtotal
subtotal_pattern = r"Subtotal: \$([\d.]+)"

# Extract subtotal using regular expression
subtotal_match = re.search(subtotal_pattern, receipt_text)

# Extracted tax base value
tax_base_value = subtotal_match.group(1) if subtotal_match else None

print("Tax Base Value:", tax_base_value)


You can customize it. Train the model on additional examples of receipts that contain tax base values. This will help the model learn to recognize and extract this specific information.

Use the Document Intelligence Sample Labeling tool to manually label the tax base value in a few sample receipts.



